# TypeError: filterCreationErrorCallback is not a function

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ropsten, web3-providers

trying to deploy contract to Ropsten network-
[image]

[image]

Comment: truffle version?

Comment: @Sanchit truffle version 3.3.0

Comment: This seems to be an open issue in web3js - https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/552